# jquery how to find nth child from element variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get 4th child from an element children. When i console element.children()

```
console.log(element.children())
```

It shows all children in array which is fine.

[image]

I want to get only 4th child , marked in red circle. I tried

```
console.log(element.find(':nth-child(4)'))
```

but it shows multiple results from subsequent children. Please help how to select nth child.
Thanks

Comment: If the children are in an array, have you tried accessing the fourth child through the array with index?

Comment: Yes that's true. I can get console.log(element.children()[4]). but i have to do further changes by putting ".css('display','inline')" which does not work when  we put index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) once like:

```
console.log( element.children().eq(3) )
```

- Using 3 here as `.eq()` is zero-based index